# How to upload files using IFormFile in C# Core with input type as file?

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, file-upload

The razor page contains the following code:

```
   <form id="myForm" asp-action="UpdateProfile" asp-controller="Home"
              data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-complete="profileupdated">
   
       <input type=text name="MyName" value=""/>
       <input type="file" id="MyImage" name="MyImage" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png">
       <button type="submit">Save</button>
   </form>
```

And C# contains following code:

```
    public class Profile
    {
      public string MyName {get;set;}
      public IFormFile MyImage {get;set}
    }
        
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProfile(Profile model)
    {
       // here the model contains value of Name but MyImage is null
       // how can I get value of MyImage which is IFormFile Type
       
    }
```

The problem is that while submitting the form, in C# method, I get the value of the MyName field but MyImage is coming NULL. How can I get the image in the method?

Note: The input type in HTML is type="file" whereas in C#, I am using IFormFile for receiving the image so I am looking for help in this particular issue. I need a solution for IFormFile type, and not the other file types for uploading images/files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag.

```
<form id="myForm" asp-action="UpdateProfile" asp-controller="Home"
          data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-complete="profileupdated" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <input type=text name="MyName" value=""/>
   <input type="file" id="MyImage" name="MyImage" class="form-control" accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png">
   <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help!